# XCode Project not saving all my files?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Alright. This is utterly puzzling.

I am developing a game project with Xcode 4.1.

The project files are always with me in an USB stick, because I am constantly developing the project on many different Macs.

So I come to a workstation, paste a copy of the project in the USB stick to the desktop, and start working on that copy. When I am done developing, I delete the project in the USB stick, and then copy the one in the workstation's desktop back to the USB stick.

For some reason, my file `GameData.h` and `GameData.m` are not properly updated. But everything else in the project is. Basically, I made some edits to `GameData`, and when I got back home, I noticed that `GameData` is not the same as the one I was editing a while back. In fact, it only has code I wrote yesterday.

What could be wrong? Why is that file the only thing that never gets copied properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to make sure your GameData.m/.h files are where you think they are.  Select one of them in the navigator tree, right click, select Show in Finder.  Examine the file it points to - is it in the same directory as it's project peers, does it have correct (writable) permissions, is it an alias to another file, etc.?

Sometimes you can get into trouble (usually with libs) by adding them to the project, but not checking the box that says "copy into destination group's folder if necessary".  In this case, XCode tries to find the file in that other directory (which may not be on all of your Mac machines) rather than the directory where all the other project files are.

Comment: Correct! Thanks :) Yeah, apparently I did not check that box when importing that specific file =/

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that occasionally xCode either fails to save a file or fails to rebuild after a file has been changed.  It seems to happen on some projects and not others (I've noticed it mostly on a desktop app, but never on phone apps).  I have no idea why this happens.

Comment: yes, quite frustrating that xcode does not acknowledge all changes and the only way you can be sure the objects/products are up to date is to delete the build directory and all dependencies = =